# load images from database into Bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am a beginner to asp.net mvc. I currently have an app with crud functionality.  The user is able save images into the database (the user inserts the image into the database using a string url in the create view).

What I would like to do is use a bootstrap carousel (in the index view/a separate controller to crud controller) that displays images stored in the database,that have been inputted by the user. Therefore if the user changes the image the carousel that displays that image will also change to the new image.

Currently, this is what I have so far in my index view:

```
<!-- Indicators -->
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
</ol>

<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
        @foreach (var item in Model) {

        <img src="@Url.Content(item.DessertArtUrl)" alt="Chania">
        }
    </div>


</div>

<!-- Left and right controls -->
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
```

The result:

You are unable to navigate from one image to another, instead
The images are placed one after another, like a stack, one image on top of another.

e.g.
Image1
Image2
Image3

as appose to:

Image1 displayed, click navigation button in the carousel and navigate to image2 etc.

How do I solve this?

Really appreciate your time and effort, thanks

EDITED-Trying to add links to the carousel images, but doesn't work:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide " style="width:400px; height: 400px; margin:0 auto" data-ride="carousel">

<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
</ol>


<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    @{int i = 0;}
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        {
            i++;
            var active = i == 1 ? "active" : "";
           <div class="item @active">

               <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Desserts", new {Id=item.Id })">
                   <img src="@Url.Content(item.DessertArtUrl)" alt="Dessert">

</div>


        }
    }
        </div>

        <!-- Left and right controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding each Image in single div with class **"item active"** which is not valid try below code hope it helps.

```
@{int i = 0;}
@foreach (var item in Model) {
{
    i++;
    var active = i == 1 ? "active" : "";
    <div class="item @active">
        <img src="@Url.Content(item.DessertArtUrl)" alt="Chania">
    </div>

}
```

***Let me UPDATE your whole code you have posted here please find below***

```
<!-- Indicators -->
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
</ol>

<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    @{int i = 0;}
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
    {
        i++;
        var active = i == 1 ? "active" : "";
        <div class="item @active">
            <img src="@Url.Content(item.DessertArtUrl)" alt="Chania">
        </div>
    }
</div>

<!-- Left and right controls -->
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
```

**Updated**

```
     <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Desserts", new {Id=item.Id })">
                   <img src="@Url.Content(item.DessertArtUrl)" alt="Dessert">
     </a>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! if I want to make the images clickable I added a url.action("action name","controllername") just above the image src. However when I did this the carousel stops working, only the first image is present. Not sure how to make the carousel work. Really appreciate your time and effort. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please update your question so I can figure out what's going wrong ??

Comment: I have updated my question as requested. Thanks again.

Comment: I have updated my question as requested. Thanks for your time

Comment: I think there is a missing closing anchor tag after img tag this caused an issue. please find my updated answer

Comment: @SwatiSinha completely my pleasure